# pip installed at a different location than python

Tags: python, windows, pip

1. When my user and system variables include:

   `C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts`

   `pip` is recognized, but `python` brings the error:

   `No Python at 'C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe`
2. When my user and system variables include:

   `C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\`

   `python` is recognized, but `pip` brings same error:

   `No Python at 'C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe`

Comment: What do you mean "user and system variables"?  Which variable exactly?

Comment: In my enviornmental variables on my computer it shows "user variables" and "system variables." My path is the same for both of those.

Comment: Oh, so you're talking about the `PATH` variable?

Comment: Yes, the Path variable.

Comment: Is this using CMD, or PowerShell?

Comment: I am using the command prompt

Comment: It looks like Python was installed into `Python38-32` and then renamed to `Python38` without reinstalling? Or perhaps the same version of Python was installed twice into these locations and then one copy was removed without uninstalling?

Comment: Yes, I think the later this is the problem, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: just use `python -m pip install abc`

Comment: I cannot use python and pip commands at the same time. This is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Windows start menu
2. Type `advanced system settings` to search for it
3. Run `Advanced system settings` tool
   ＊Alternatively you may run `sysdm.cpl` in command line and move to `Advanced` tab
4. Press `Environment Variables...` button in bottom of the window
5. Find variable named `Path` in `User variables` list and click it
6. Search for lines with `Python38-32` folder and update it with `Python38`
   ＊If here is no `...\Python38-32\...` path just do nothing
7. Repeat ⑤ and ⑥ steps for `System variables` list

If all variables set correctly but problem still happens try to check [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/j7iul3/no_python_at/) on reddit:

> For anyone who is having this problem, the pyvenv.cfg file in the same directory where you installed your virtual environment has a variable named 'HOME' that the virtual environment uses to look for Python. If you've changed your Python install location after setting up the virtual environment, you'll have to change the variable to match the current path to your Python executable.

Comment: I don't understand how a wrong `PATH` variable would result in the very specific `No Python at ...` message.  Wouldn't it just say `python: command not found`?  I feel like there is a deeper problem here than just a wrong path.

Comment: @JohnGordon Not sure but probably that is because only one of python paths changed ( `...\ ` and `...\Scripts` should be correct)?

Comment: When I update it to Python 38, python works, but pip gives me the same error. So basically I have been deleting and adding in /Scripts from my enviornmental variables depending on if I need to use the python or pip command. It works, but it is just a pain. This only became a problem when I upgraded to Windows 11 btw.